# Training Form for Mobile device

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to be able to create a form that can be used on a laptop or mobile device and once completed, submit and have the data sent to my email address.

Is this an option with Cognito Forms?

If so, how do I go about it?

Comment: Can create form easily with cognito which are compatible on desktop and mobile and can setup email notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question! I’m a developer for Cognito Forms.

Cognito Forms are responsive, so they can be easily used on desktop, tablet or mobile devices without any loss of functionality. Additionally, they can be set up to send email notifications any time a new entry is received, and can include or omit details of each submission.

To set up email notifications, open the editor for the form you’d like to modify. Under Submission Settings, check the box next to “Receive email notifications?”. Add one or more email addresses under “Recipients”, and check “Include details?” to show submission information in the email.

If you need additional help with this, please visit our [help topic](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/20/building-forms/notification-emails).

Please let me know if you have any other questions.